# SQL query count pics and get cover image

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table pictures with attributes pictureId, albumName, isCover picture.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|   id   | albumName | coverPic |
+--------+-----------+----------+
| String | String    | Boolean  |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I need to write query to get number of pics in each album and get id of cover pic for each album. I wrote this query and I get number of pics but I dont know how to get id of cover image for each album.

```
SELECT ALBUM as album, count(ALBUM) as  picsInAlbum, PICTURE_ID as pictureId 
FROM PICTURES 
group by ALBUM, PICTURE_ID
```

FOR example:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|   id   | albumName |isCover   |
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 1      | test      | true     |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 2      | test      | false    |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 3      | test1      | true    |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 4      | test1      | false   |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 5      | test2      | true    |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| 6      | test2      | false   |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

As query result I need this.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| ALBUM  |PICSINALBUM|coverPicId
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| test   | 2         | 1        |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| test1  | 2         | 3        |
+--------+-----------+----------+
+--------+-----------+----------+
| test2  | 2         | 5        |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have only one table not tables. Its table picture with attributes id, albumName, and is coverPic. String, String and boolean

Comment: You need to use your current query as a delivered table and inner self join that result with your table..

Comment: You have only one table to regroup pictures in album with a cover (that the first mistake ;) ). How do you know which picture is the cover of the album ? if `PICTURE_ID` is defined ?

Comment: @AxelH Better now ?

Comment: @AxelH I have field is_cover

Answer (score 2):

Conditional aggregation.  Do a test on each row to determine if this row is the "cover picture" for the album.  If it is, return the picture_id, otherwise return NULL. And then use an aggregate function to pick out a non-NULL value.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT p.album                                AS album
      , COUNT(p.album)                         AS picsInAlbum
      , MAX(IF(p.isCover=1,p.picture_id,NULL)) AS pictureId 
   FROM `PICTURES` p 
  GROUP
     BY p.album
```

---

NOTE: The MySQL `IF()` function could be replaced with a more portable ANSI standards equivalent

```
      , MAX(CASE WHEN p.isCover = 1 THEN p.picture_id ELSE NULL END) AS pictureId
```

NOTE: using lowercase for table names is a recommended pattern.

> ... it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables **using lowercase** names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: There would be no need to specify `null` in case expression let the DBMS to handle `null`s.

Comment: @YogeshSharma: yes, that is correct, the ELSE NULL can be omitted to achieve the same result.

Comment: error Expecting "LPAREN", got "MAX" at line 3, column 9.

Comment: @Hajrudin  the syntax provided in this answer executes with no error in MySQL. (note that the question is tagged with [mysql].  sqlfiddle demonstration here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d79b9/1